# While (( c = getc(file)) != EOF) loop won't stop executing

Tags: c, file, input, output

I can't figure out why my while loop won't work. The code works fine without it... The purpose of the code is to find a secret message in a bin file. So I got the code to find the letters, but now when I try to get it to loop until the end of the file, it doesn't work. I'm new at this. What am I doing wrong?

```
main(){

FILE* message;
int i, start;
long int size;
char keep[1];

message = fopen("c:\\myFiles\\Message.dat", "rb");

if(message == NULL){
    printf("There was a problem reading the file. \n");
    exit(-1);
}

//the first 4 bytes contain an int that tells how many subsequent bytes you can throw away
fread(&start, sizeof(int), 1, message);
printf("%i \n", start); //#of first 4 bytes was 280
fseek(message, start, SEEK_CUR); //skip 280 bytes
keep[0] = fgetc(message); //get next character, keep it
printf("%c", keep[0]); //print character

while( (keep[0] = getc(message)) != EOF) {
    fread(&start, sizeof(int), 1, message);
    fseek(message, start, SEEK_CUR);
    keep[0] = fgetc(message);
    printf("%c", keep[0]);
}

fclose(message);

system("pause");
}
```

EDIT:

After looking at my code in the debugger, it looks like having "getc" in the while loop threw everything off. I fixed it by creating a new char called letter, and then replacing my code with this:

```
fread(&start, sizeof(int), 1, message);
fseek(message, start, SEEK_CUR);

while( (letter = getc(message)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", letter);
    fread(&start, sizeof(int), 1, message);
    fseek(message, start, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

It works like a charm now. Any more suggestions are certainly welcome. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the loop condition with feof?

Comment: @user1161318: That introduces an error, remember that `feof()` only returns true *after* trying to read past the last byte.

Comment: You haven't told us what doesn't work. What are the results you are getting, and what are the results that you want to get? This will help us help you find the answer.

Comment: @user1161318: `feof` is basically never correct.

Comment: There's no point in having an array that's only 1 element - just use `char keep` and get rid of the `[0]` everywhere.

Comment: Actually, keep should be an int to fix.  See JonathanLeffler's answer.  To @user1695758, if Jonathan's answer takes care of it, please be sure to accept it.

Comment: I was sort of crashing through the code, so there are a lot of extraneous things I left in it. I fixed it up though, and it's nice and clean. Working on a second solution to see if I can use less lines of code with Jonathan's advice.

Answer (score 19):

The return value from `getc()` and its relatives is an `int`, not a `char`.

If you assign the result of `getc()` to a `char`, one of two things happens when it returns `EOF`:

- If plain `char` is unsigned, then EOF is converted to 0xFF, and 0xFF != EOF, so the loop never terminates.
- If plain `char` is signed, then EOF is equivalent to a valid character (in the 8859-1 code set, that's ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS), and your loop may terminate early.

Given the problem you face, we can tentatively guess you have plain `char` as an unsigned type.

The reason that `getc()` et al return an `int` is that they have to return every possible value that can fit in a `char` and also a distinct value, EOF.  In the C standard, it says:

> **ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.7.1 The `fgetc()` function**
>
> `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`
>
> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by `stream` is not set and a
>   next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` ...
>
> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-
>   file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns EOF.

Similar wording applies to the `getc()` function and the `getchar()` function: they are defined to behave like the `fgetc()` function except that if `getc()` is implemented as a macro, it may take liberties with the file stream argument that are not normally granted to standard macros — specifically, the stream argument expression may be evaluated more than once, so calling `getc()` with side-effects (`getc(fp++)`) is very silly (but change to `fgetc()` and it would be safe, but still eccentric).

---

In your loop, you could use:

```
int c;

while ((c = getc(message)) != EOF) {
    keep[0] = c;
```

This preserves the assignment to `keep[0]`; I'm not sure you truly need it.

You should be checking the other calls to `fgets()`, `getc()`, `fread()` to make sure you are getting what you expect as input.  Especially on input, you cannot really afford to skip those checks.  Sooner, rather than later, something will go wrong and if you aren't religiously checking the return statuses, your code is likely to crash, or simply 'go wrong'.

Comment: +1 I was thinking this was the problem but had no idea how to word it so succinctly.

Comment: Upvoted too.  Recommend you tell him explicitly how to fix (declare keep as an int) so there's no reason not to accept yours as the answer.

Comment: Thanks!! I understand what was going on a lot better now.

Answer (score 2):

There are 256 different `char` values that might be returned by `getc()` and stored in a `char` variable like `keep[0]` (yes, I'm oversummarising wildly).  To detect end-of-file reliably, `EOF` has to have a value different from all of them.  That's why `getc()` returns `int` rather than `char`: because a 257th distinct value for `EOF` wouldn't fit into a `char`.

Thus you need to store the value returned by `getc()` in an `int` at least until you check it against `EOF`:

```
int tmpc;
while( (tmpc = getc(message)) != EOF) {
    keep[0] = tmpc;
    ...
```

Comment: Maybe instead "... because 257 distinct values wouldn't fit into a `char`".  OP's system, certainly windows,  `char` that is signed _does_ hold `EOF` which is likely -1.  It just cannot distinguish between `EOF` and `(char) 255`.

Comment: @chux: Indeed, that's what *distinct* means.