# Squeeze blank lines into one blank line in C

Tags: c

Hello to refer to the  same question but different code.

[Replacing multiple new lines in a file with just one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065683/replacing-multiple-new-lines-in-a-file-with-just-one/44448650?noredirect=1#comment75895074_44448650)

```
int main(void){

    format();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void format(){
    int c;
    size_t nlines = 1;
    size_t nspace = 0;

    while (( c= getchar()) != EOF ){

        /*TABS*/
        if(c == '\t'){
            c = ' ';
        }
        /*SPACES*/
        if (c ==' '){
            if(nspace > 0){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                putchar(c);
                nspace++;
                nlines = 0;
            }
        }

        /*NEW LINE*/
        else if(c == '\n'){
            if(++nlines >2){
                continue;
            }
            else {
                nlines++;
                nspace = 0;
            }
            putchar(c);
        }   
        else{
            putchar(c);
            nspace = 0;
            nlines = 0;
        }       
    }
}
```

I want to squeeze multiple blank lines into one blank line but it doesn't seem to work and on Cygwin terminal at the stdout, last line gives me extra blank line although the input doesn't have the blank line at the end.

**For example**
*INPUT*

```
Hello   Hi\n
\n
\n
Hey\t\tHola\n
```

*DESIRED OUTPUT*

```
Hello Hi\n
\n
Hey Hola\n
```

*ACTUAL OUTPUT*

```
Hello Hi\n
Hey Hola\n
```

Please explain!

Comment: output you provided is output you want or output you are getting.

Comment: `isspace()` can make your code more compact and simple for reading

Comment: Do **not** modify your code after you've gotten answers in such a way that you invalidate the answers.  That is not kosher at all.

Comment: my instructor doesn't like it. I used nested while loop which worked but I had to redo because he doesn't like it. Thank you anyway! @VolAnd

Comment: oh I am so sorry! I thought it would be great for people. I am so sorry. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements and prototypes for the sub functions (like `void format( void );`

Comment: @user3629249 obviously we all know we need that so I didn't post it from the beginning. :) That's also not the point.

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem (as your question is), there are certain requirements that must be met.  Otherwise the question is considered 'off topic' and will be voted to be closed.  The requirements are: 1) post a cleanly compiles, short code that still has the problem.  2) post the actual inputs 3) post the expected outputs 4) post the actual outputs.  Your question is 'off topic' because the posted code does not cleanly compile.  As far as 'well all know we need that'  Are you expecting us to guess as to what header files you actually included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variant of your code.  I eliminated the `format()` function (which is unusual for me since most programs on SO don't use enough functions) incorporating it directly into `main()`.  The code treats spaces and newlines more symmetrically now, fixing the double increment problem also identified in [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44449520).  It also only prints out a newline at the end if there wasn't already a newline at the end.  That normalizes files which do not end with a newline.  The initialization of `nlines = 1;` deals with multiple newlines at the start of the file — that was well done already.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    size_t nlines = 1;
    size_t nspace = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\t')
            c = ' ';
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (nspace < 1)
            {
                putchar(c);
                nspace++;
                nlines = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (c == '\n')
        {
            if (nlines < 2)
            {
                putchar(c);
                nlines++;
                nspace = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
            nspace = 0;
            nlines = 0;
        }
    }
    if (nlines == 0)
        putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

My testing uses some Bash-specific notations.  My program was `sb73`:
The last of test input does not include a final newline.  The outputs use ⌴ to indicate a newline in the output:

```
$ echo $'Hello   Hi\n\n\nHey\t\tHola\n' | sb73
Hello Hi⌴
⌴
Hey Hola
⌴
$
```

and:

```
$ echo $'\n\nHello   Hi\n\n\n    Hey\t\tHola\n' | sb73
⌴
Hello Hi⌴
⌴
 Hey Hola⌴
⌴
$
```

and:

```
$ printf '%s' $'\n\nHello   Hi\n\n\n    Hey\t\tHola' | sb73
⌴
Hello Hi⌴
⌴
 Hey Hola⌴
$
```

#### Handling CRLF line endings

The comments identify that the code above doesn't work on a Cygwin terminal, and the plausible reason is that the data being modified has CRLF line endings.  There are various ways around this.  One is to find a way of forcing the standard input into text mode.  In text mode, CRLF line endings should be mapped to Unix-style `'\n'` (NL or LF only) endings on input, and Unix-style line ending should be mapped to CRLF line endings on output.

Alternatively, it would be possible simply to ignore CR characters:

```
--- sb73.c  2017-06-08 22:04:28.000000000 -0700
+++ sb47.c  2017-06-08 22:40:24.000000000 -0700
@@ -19,6 +19,8 @@
                 nlines = 0;
             }
         }
+        else if (c == '\r')
+            continue;    // Windows?
         else if (c == '\n')
         {
             if (nlines < 2)
```

That's a 'unified diff' showing two extra lines in the code.  Or it is possible to handle CR not followed by LF as a regular character and yet handle CR followed by LF as a newline combination:

```
--- sb73.c  2017-06-08 22:04:28.000000000 -0700
+++ sb59.c  2017-06-08 22:42:43.000000000 -0700
@@ -19,6 +19,17 @@
                 nlines = 0;
             }
         }
+        else if (c == '\r')
+        {
+            if ((c = getchar()) == '\n')
+            {
+               ungetc(c, stdin);
+               continue;
+            }
+            putchar('\r');
+            nspace = 0;
+            nlines = 0;
+        }
         else if (c == '\n')
         {
             if (nlines < 2)
```

There's probably a way to write a state machine that handles CR, but that would be more complex.

I have a `utod` program that converts Unix-style line endings to Windows-style; I used that in the pipeline to test the new variants of the code.

Comment: thank you so much! now on my Cygwin terminal works properly! it doesn't give me extra blank line

Comment: It is funny how it doesn't work on my Cygwin terminal. It doesn't squeeze multiple blank lines.

Comment: On Windows, if the standard input is not 'text' mode, you will get a `'\r'` and a `'\n'` for each line ending, and the code shown treats `'\r'` as an 'other' character.  It can be modified to handle CRLF.  One simple way is by ignoring `'\r'` altogether.  Another possibility is that there's a WIndows-specific way to put standard input into text mode.  Or a more radical modification can be made.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there's [`setmode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx), but `stdin` should be in text mode by default...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: thanks for the function name — it isn't one I've needed to memorize.  I'm a little surprised that standard input was not in text mode, but maybe it is something to do with Cygwin.  OTOH, it seems to be a plausible explanation for what is going wrong because the code shown should work fine if the CRLF to newline mapping was occurring.  It could be something else, but I'd be quite surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `nlines` twice:

```
else if(c == '\n'){
    if(++nlines >2){  /* incremented here */
        continue;
    }
    else {
        nlines++;     /* incremented here */
        nspace = 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

You just want to do it once.  I'd suggest just incrementing the counter until it hits 2 and then not incrementing it any more.  That just means  a small change:

```
    if(nlines >= 2){
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Hello I modifed my working code except on Cygwin terminal, it gives me extran ending lines.

Comment: @dyingStudent: Your code unconditionally adds a newline at the end of the output — which is evidently not what you want.  However, your code also doesn't recognize whether the file ended without a newline.  You can see how I resolved it in my answer.