# logical mistake in writing function htoi

Tags: c

I've written this semi-htoi function in c that takes a hexadecimal string and turns it to hexadecimal int.

*if I correct this, I can turn it to real htoi function

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char c;
int a = 0x0;
//a += 1;if do this, we have added 1 to 0 hexadecimal
while((c = getchar()) != '`')
{
    if((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')){
        a = a * 16 + (c - '0');
        printf("a is:%x c:%c\n", a, c);
    }
    else if((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f')){
        a = a * 16 + c;
        printf("a is:%x c:%c\n", a, c);
    }
    else if((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F')){
        a = a * 16 + c;
        printf("a is:%x c:%c\n", a, c);
    }
}
printf("\nyour hexa number is:\n%hhx\n", a);
return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work, while if I change 
`a = a * 16 + c`
to 
`a = a * 10 + c`

and
`int a = 0x0`
to 
`int a = 0`
it work as atoi

Comment: The second and third case doesn't turn the letter into a number

Comment: the third case isn't doing that properly either. `a = a * 16 + c -'a'+10`

Comment: plz give me correct code

Comment: Oh no. It's your task.

Comment: You do a conversion of the character in question for the 0-9 case.  You need to do the same for the A-F and a-f case.

Comment: do u mean a = a * 16 + (c - 'a')?

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reason. Read about the functions you use.

Comment: Almost. `a` is corresponding to `10`, not to `0`.... so...

Comment: tnx my friend. i've corrected by adding a = a*16 + (c - 'a' + 10)

Comment: I presume that this is some kind of academic exercise, yes?  Because standard library's `strtol()` function can already do what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is your `printf()` statement:

```
printf("\nyour hexa number is:\n%hhx\n", a);
```

The `%hhx` conversion specification says 'treat the argument as an `unsigned char`'.  That isn't what you want.  You should use:

```
printf("\nyour hexa number is: %x\n", a);
```

(I replaced the newline after the colon with a space — the output will look better that way.  It isn't a necessary change.)

Another problem is the conversion code for hexadecimal characters, as documented in the comments.

Yet another problem is that `getchar()` returns an `int` and not a `char`.
See [`while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)` loop won't stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694394/while-c-getcfile-eof-loop-wont-stop-executing) for more details.  Also, your loop should terminate on EOF and should probably terminate on newline too.  You stop on a back-tick without generating an error; you ignore other non-hexadecimal characters.

You should also consider using `isdigit()` and `isxdigit()` and maybe `tolower()` or `toupper()` from `<ctype.h>`.  The `a`..`f` check works on all ASCII and EBCDIC code sets, but if you were testing a much bigger range (e.g. `a`..`i`), then your comparison would not be reliable for EBCDIC.

Putting all the suggestions together, I would produce something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int a = 0x0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '`' && c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            a = a * 16 + (c - '0');
            printf("a is: %x c:%c\n", a, c);
        }
        else if (isxdigit(c))
        {
            a = a * 16 + (toupper(c) - 'A' + 10);
            printf("a is: %x c:%c\n", a, c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("'%c' is not a hexadecimal digit\n", c);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nYour hexadecimal number is: %x\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'd be very tempted to remove the test for back-quote and let the 'not a hexadecimal digit' code deal with it.

Sample runs of `hx53` — created from `hx53.c` and using Bash [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) to provide the input:

```
$ hx53 <<< 'a32419fC'
a is: a c:a
a is: a3 c:3
a is: a32 c:2
a is: a324 c:4
a is: a3241 c:1
a is: a32419 c:9
a is: a32419f c:f
a is: a32419fc c:C

Your hexadecimal number is: a32419fc
$ hx53 <<< 'a32419`fC'
a is: a c:a
a is: a3 c:3
a is: a32 c:2
a is: a324 c:4
a is: a3241 c:1
a is: a32419 c:9

Your hexadecimal number is: a32419
$ hx53 <<< 'a32419XfC'
a is: a c:a
a is: a3 c:3
a is: a32 c:2
a is: a324 c:4
a is: a3241 c:1
a is: a32419 c:9
'X' is not a hexadecimal digit

Your hexadecimal number is: a32419
$
```

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to `isxdigit()`.