# How to read a file that was fseeked?

Tags: c, io, stream, fseek

I have no idea why this does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("txt2","wr");
    if(!fp) return 1;

    fprintf(fp,"20");
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);   
    fprintf(fp,"19");
    rewind(fp);
    
    char c;
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
        printf("%c",c);
}
```

Here should be write `20`, then rewrite to `19`, set the position to start of file, and the read the char till EOF (so should print `19`). But prints nothing. Why is that?

I have tried to make better check for return poitner to `fp` (because of `wr`):

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("txt","wr");
    if(!fp){
        printf("nada\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But it compiles without problem. Why is that? The `wr` should be UB (and thus cause segfault or another err) or?

Comment: Note that `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Placing the `int` from `fgetc()` into a `char` value can make identifying `EOF` correctly impossible.

Comment: it compiles, even with `wr` as flags

Comment: @milanHrabos the compiler doesn't check the content of the mode string to determine if it's valid. That's up to you. To the compiler, it's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode `"wr"` is not valid string for POSIX [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) or Microsoft [`fopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019).  You probably want to use `"w+"`. Using `"r+"` would be an alternative, but then the file must exist before you open it.

The implementation of `fopen()` that you're using probably treats `"wr"` as equivalent to `"w"` (unless it reports an error and your program exits — it is a good idea to report why you are exiting).  You can't read from a write-only file stream.

Strictly, you should also use `int` and not `char` for the variable `c` because [`fgetc()` returns an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694394/while-c-getcfile-eof-loop-wont-stop-executing/13694450#13694450).

Comment: There is no report or error, the gcc does not hepled here (So it is UB). Anyway thanks

Comment: the solution could be thisone (after changing flags in fopen to w+): `for(int c;(c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF;printf("%c",c));`

Comment: The way that `fopen()` reports the error is by returning `NULL`.  You test for the `NULL` pointer (that's good), but you don't write a message to the user if the program fails to open the file.  It just exits with an error status via the `return 1;` which requires testing at the command line.  You're using C99 or later semantics in `main()` — you have no final `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: yes, I do not use `return 0` at the end of main, because main is usually the last process running, and no other process is after (and therefor waiting for return exit status). So I consider using exit status of main to be redundant

Comment: I disagree about the final `return 0;`, but the C standard committee allows you to get away with omitting it as long as you aren't using C90 (so I disagree with the C standard committee — I don't think it was a good change, but it was made in part for compatibility with C++, where the considerations are different).

Comment: But of course, the exit status of main could be still good for debugging purposes

Comment: see my edits. even though making the checking be verbose, it still compile and does not segaful, how's that possible?

Comment: It compiles because it is syntactically correct; it links because there are no undefined references.  When it runs, the `nada` message would appear if the local `fopen()` reports the erroneous mode argument.  (The error message should be printed to `stderr`, but that's a minor problem.). If `nada` does not appear, then the file is open for writing; when you try to read from the write-only file stream, you immediately get `EOF` returned from `fgetc ()`, so the program produces no output at all.  Note that the compiler does not check the `fopen()` mode argument; that is only checked at run-time.

Comment: so can you please add to your answer a proper handling of errournous fopen? What to change in order to see the `nada` message?

Comment: There is no way to report `nada` if the implementation of `fopen()` looks at the string `"wr"` and says "oh, that's a write-only mode" and gets on with life.  Or, more accurately, you'd have to do the comparison of the mode string to the values listed in the relevant documentation and then report "my programmer did not read the manual and miscoded the open mode, even though it was a literal string and the test for the invalid mode was a lot harder to write than simply using a valid string".  A better error message would include the file name.  You'd probably write a function to check the mode.

Comment: Ok, I see the irony. However, when someony really mistype the open mode in critical app, there should be a method to check this error. Because the fopen will give me valid pointer regardless of flag used, so I cannot check that pointer, but what else should i check? there is nothing to ensure, the open was done properly and will not cause a huge problem more later and cause unexpected results (because IO here is important)

Comment: If you supply a mode such as `"z"` or `"+w"`, you will likely get a null pointer from `fopen()`. If the mode supplied has a valid mode as a prefix, it is quite common for the valid prefix to be used and the remainder ignored. If you want to be sure that a variable mode is wholly valid, you'd have to write a wrapper function that validates the mode and then calls `fopen()` if it is OK (returning `NULL` if it is not, and maybe setting `errno` to `EINVAL` or thereabouts if it is not OK). The wrapper might or might not report the error on `stderr` — that depends on the constraints in your program.