# Why does while((c = getchar()) != EOF) repeat 2 times in c programming?

Tags: c, while-loop, eof, getchar

When I enter a number from keyboard, while loop goes 2 times, and I didn't understand why it is doing that. I want to run this loop for one time after each entering number.  Is there anyone who can explain this situation?

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        printf("c = %c\n", c);
        
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i< 10; i++){
            printf("%d in loop\n", i);
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d - at EOF\n", c);
}
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY17n.png)

I want to make this source code work truly.

Comment: `'\n'` (newline) is a character as well. To stop that from happening you could add `&& c != '\n'` in your while loops condition.

Comment: Use `int c`, not `char c`!  See [`while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)` loop won't stop executing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13694394/15168) amongst other questions.  Whether this is actually causing your problem is less clear.

Comment: See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168)

Comment: I get the same results you do for your code, so it's not your system or compiler, etc.   All the methods I've seen for solving this are not portable or not in compliance (invoke undefined behavior) or both.  I've also tried all the suggestions in this comment section so far --all of them good --  but to no avail.  Following this question...

Answer (score 1):

> why does `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)` repeat 2 times in c programming (?)

Because OP pressed 2 keys: <kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> before signaling end-of-file.
The `for` loop ran once for each character: `'6'` and `'\n'`.

---

> I want to run this loop for one time after each entering number.

It appears OP wants to run the loop per each *digit*.
Amend code to only run the loop when the key is a digit:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { // add
    for (i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
        printf("%d in loop\n", i);
    }
} // add
```

Or use `if (isdigit(c)) {`.

Additional code needed if input like <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> is to be handled as 1 *number* and then run the `for` loop once.

---

Change `char c;` to `int c;` as typically `char` encodes 256 different values and `int getchar()` returns 257 different values. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77503957/why-does-whilec-getchar-eof-repeat-2-times-in-c-programming/77504493#comment136635175_77503957)